# How to validate a number has a 2 decimal place precision with javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to check if a number has a 2 decimal place precision. I know how to convert a number to a 2 decimal place precision like this:

```
var myNumber = 2.456;
var currentNumber = parseFloat(myNumber);
currentNumber = currentNumber.toFixed(2); 
console.log(currentNumber);
```

so If I enter:

- 1 this will turn into 1.00
- 2.457 this will turn into 2.46

but how can I check if the result of my code has a 2 decimal place precision? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You can just split the number by the radix character (`.` in your case), and check if the second element in the array is exactly two characters long and contains only digits. But in hindsight this verification doesn't make sense since `.toFixed(2)` will _always_ create a string-like number with two decimal places.

Comment: You do realize that the result `2.46` for instance, is a string, while the other is a Number. you can parse the string to test for chars after the `.`.

Comment: Terry and @RandyCasburn can you post a solution, please? Thanks

Comment: @RandyCasburn `Number.prototype.toFixed()` always returns a string...? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#return_value

Comment: @Devmix Did you read the last part of my comment? `Number.prototype.toFixed(2)` will always return a number with two decimal precision. Not sure what you're looking for? `1.00` is a number with two decimal precision for example.

Comment: @Terry - This is the quote from your reference: "_A string representing the given number using fixed-point notation._" - What is your question?

Comment: @Terry - Don't take my word for it, run this in the browser console: `(1234).toFixed().constructor
`

Comment: @Devmix - Solution: `(2.456).toFixed(2).split(".")[1].length === 2`; you can replace `(2.456)` with the variable name containing the value. Example:  `number.toFixed(2).split(".")[1].length === 2`

Comment: Spectric's answer is correct (I didn't see it before my previous comment)

Comment: As a note `var currentNumber = parseFloat(myNumber);` does not make any sense in the give case. Both `myNumber` and `currentNunber` are a Number values represented as Float. What that line does is converting the `myNumber` into a String value and then parsing it again into a Number value.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Floating point numbers have whatever precision they have, you cannot check whether they have two decimal places of accuracy in a meaningful way, and it's not useful to do so.  It's only when you format a number as a string that it makes sense to consider how many digits appear after the `.`. You cannot feed the numeric literal `1.00` into any function and have it tell you whether it has two decimal places, because that doesn't make sense. Never mind scenarios like `0.21` + `0.24`, which produces `0.44999999999999996`. Does that have "two decimal places"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the number into a string, split by a period and check whether the second item's length is 2:

```js
function isPrecise(num){
  return String(num).split(".")[1]?.length == 2;
}

console.log(isPrecise(1.23))
console.log(isPrecise(1.2))
console.log(isPrecise(1))
console.log(isPrecise("1.23")) //works if its a string too
```

You can also use a regex:

```js
function isPrecise(num){
  return /\d+\.\d{2}/gm.test(String(num));
}

console.log(isPrecise(1.23))
console.log(isPrecise(1.2))
console.log(isPrecise("1.23")) //works if its a string too
```

Comment: For completeness: I would also mention that Number values are represented as floats. So at some point, it might not produce the expected result like `isPrecise(90071992547410.09)` would result in `false`. But maybe that's what the OP is actually looking for. Anyhow for future readers, this might not be obvious.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, because the requirements don't make sense. It's impossible for somebody to enter `1.2` with two decimals of accuracy, the numeric literal `1.20` is represented as the floating point value `1.2` even if you enter `1.20`.

Comment: @Spectric your solution doesn't work with 12.00, any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Devmix Because JavaScript converts `12.00` to `12` (it truncates the number).

Comment: @Spectric any way to make it pass (return true) if a user enters 12.00 ?

Comment: @Devmix You can try ensuring the passed value is a string. E.g, if its the value of an input, use `.value` instead of `.valueAsNumber`

Comment: @Devmix The provided solutions in my answer already work for strings.

Comment: @Spectric got it! thanks